# NullPointerException getting Google Map in Fragment with AppCompat v21

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-appcompat

I have a strange issue with new AppCompat. I have added Google Map to fragment and it is working perfect with AppCompat v20, but if I compile my project with AppCompat v21 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'` I get NullPointer while trying to get map:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".ActivityMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
12-05 12:05:13.393    2747-2747/app.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.myapp/app.myapp.views.ActivityDrawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at app.myapp.views.FragmentMap.setUpMapIfNeeded(FragmentMap.java:178)
            at app.myapp.views.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:84)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It is some kind of v21 bug or what?

Comment: The problem is in line 178 of your FragmentMap class. I'd guess that getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map) is returning null.

Comment: I know that. But why? With AppCompat v20 this code is working, but with AppCompat v21 it returning Null

Comment: Because the FragmentManager doesn't contain a Fragment with the ID you have given. I doubt this has something to do with the different AppCompat version.

Comment: hmmm so it is map fragment in fragment? so why don't you use getChildFragmentManager() ?

Comment: Thanks, its working! `getChildFragmentManager() ` helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getChildFragment` if you are using fragment

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```